# installing fonts on windows texlive 2016 oxsz5.tfm

Tags: fonts, texlive, windows, installing-fonts

I'm trying to install a set of fonts but unsuccessful.  (oxford uni but poor documentation) 
http://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/mike/fuzz/
https://iainhouston.com/blog/z_on_osx.html

I have bunch of tfm files, a bunch of mf files and a bunch of pk files.

I using windows 7 and texlive 2016.

I tried copying all these files to:

```
C:\texlive\2016\texmf-var\fonts\tfm\fuzz
```

and then to:

```
C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\source\local
```

I've ran mktexlsr and udmap but I get `cannot find oxsz10 in map files`.  Do you have any tip on how to do (I guess the mapping of the fonts?) I don't have any map files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found in the `tgz`  various `.mf` and a `fuzz.sty`. Move the `mf` to `\texmf-local\fonts\source\local`  and the `sty` to `\texmf-local\tex\latex`. Then run mktexlsr (probably not needed, but doesn't harm) and then try to compile as a test the `tut.tex` in the `tgz`.

The fonts are metafonts, so no map-file is involved. The needed `.tfm` and `.pk` files are normally created during the compilation.

Comment: For some reason the texmf-local didn't work.  I ended up creating a new directory fuzz, updating texmf.cnf, and moving the *.sty to fuzz\latex and *.mf to fuzz\fonts\source\local.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers though! :)

Comment: This is failing now that I'm trying to use `\emph`  I get Font U/oxsz/m/n/7=oxsz7 at 7.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. ...ph

Comment: The mf is in the folder, so it sound as if the generation of the tfm failed for you (works fine for me). But what do expect to get from using \emph? The font contains no chars, only some symbols. It is not meant for normal text use.

Comment: I didn't expect the font to be applied everywhere. Indeed my intention was to emph something other than the equations.   But you're right in spite of the error I can get it to work on the document normally and I'm unlikely to apply emph to the equation symbols.